# From HTTP request received json is chopped off

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, express, body-parser

I'm trying to receive a JSON in my endpoint and sometimes that works perfectly fine. Sometimes the JSON is randomly chopped off, so that the JSON unexpectedly ends. I also have to retrieve the data from the request object very weird like that.

```
JSON.parse(String.fromCodePoint(...req._readableState.buffer.head.data)).value;
```

I confirmed with a test server, that the data in question should just be in `req.body.value` like one would expect.

My guess was that there is something wrong with `express` and that I need `body-parser`
But I'm using express version 4.17.1 which should already include the express parser build on body-parser.

I also declared it with

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false, limit: '5mb'}));
```

I'm no expert at the topic and would appreciate any help.

Could the mistake be anywhere else?

Can I try to explicitly declare for a specific endpoint to use the express parser?

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

---

Edit

```
    router.post('/route/', async (req, res) => {
        if (!req.auth(res, Object.values(globals.levels))) return;
        let data = JSON.parse(String.fromCodePoint(...req._readableState.buffer.head.data)).value;
        // Further logic
    });
```

[JSON](https://pastebin.com/ZVZZ59dB)

Comment: First of all, you're doing a `HTTP` request? Nothing fancy like `stream`?

And to answer to your question, you can mount the `express parser` individually. just use it like middleware

` app.get('/someRoute', express.json(), (req,res) => {
// Your logic
})`

Comment: @Darkripper yeah, it's an HTTP request, not a stream, let me try mounting the parser specifically, maybe it helps for some reason.

Comment: Based on your code, you've already mounted the JSON and urlencoded parser for all route.

Could you share more on what data is being pass, the routes, and maybe the size of your JSON?

Comment: @Darkripper the JSON is about 35kB big and consists of 2 key value pairs from which the second value is a 2d array containing almost all data. The application is kinda big which makes it hard to share, what of the routes do you want to know?

Comment: Just the route that your data is passing through will do

Comment: @Darkripper I've included it now. `JSON.parse()` throws an exception because the JSON ends unexpectedly. But the actual error happens before that. The way the data is extracted is completely wrong but the body is empty

Comment: if JSON end unexpectedly, you're not getting a valid JSON. Share the data structure of that JSON instead.

Either your req.body or something else that you're sending.

I can't see what is wrong just from the variable name =x

Comment: @Darkripper I know that I'm not getting a valid JSON. What I need is the reason for that which isn't in the JSON. The sent JSON is valid, the parser fails independent of payload. Nevertheless, I've included it in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230079/discussion-between-darkripper-and-ruben).